# How to use VXLAN to connect netns under multiple subnets like K8S's Flannel？

Tags: networking, network-namespaces

I have used

```
$ ip link add vxlan0 type vxlan \
        id 42 \
        dstport 4789 \
        group 239.1.1.1 \
        dev enp0s8
```

and

```
$ ip link add vxlan0 type vxlan \
    id 42 \
    dstport 4789 \
    remote 192.168.8.101 \
    local 192.168.8.100 \
    dev enp0s8
```

but neither of them can connect to multiple machines across subnets. (multicast cannot cross subnets). So what can I do to connect to the network namespace under multiple subnets like the K8S Fannel? thanks for your help

Comment: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-vxlan-linux#without-multicast

Comment: It was very useful, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to route multicasts between subnets, no matter if your infrastructure uses vxlan or not, you normally need to run additional services like [smcroute](https://github.com/troglobit/smcroute), [mrouted](https://github.com/troglobit/mrouted) or [pimd](https://github.com/troglobit/pimd)